# Google Measurement Protocol not showing events

Tags: measurement-protocol

I am trying to add a new event using Google Measurement Protocol. To test it, I'm sending a GET request to:

> http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=TIDHERE&t=event&cid=b541778c-8640-4f52-b1b6-3b18d9e58c0c&ec=Cat&ea=Action&el=label&ev=value

However, I can't see any events reported in Behavior Events. I can't see any Real time event either. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer as soon as I created the question. `ev` must be a number.

> http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=TIDHERE&t=event&cid=b541778c-8640-4f52-b1b6-3b18d9e58c0c&ec=Cat&ea=Action&el=label&ev=1

Comment: https://google-analytics.com/debug/collect?v=1&tid=TIDHERE&t=event&cid=1234&ec=Cat&ea=Action&el=label&ev= This will show you a debug message with details of problems